# EF Metadata Class not working

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I seem to be having trouble creating a metadata class for my generated model classes. I have created the below code, but Resharper is telling me that the partial class is a partial class with a single part. The actual Membership generated class is in another project in the same solution. Would that be the problem?

```
[MetadataType(typeof(MembershipViewModel))]
public partial class Membership
{
}

public class MembershipViewModel
{
    [Required, StringLength(3, MinimumLength = 3, ErrorMessage = "Format: (045/135)")]
    [DisplayAttribute(Name = "Report Cycle")]
    public string ReportCycle { get; set; }   
}
```

Comment: You can't split partial classes across projects, unfortunately.

Comment: Entity Framework's Fluent Configuration API will do some of the things you're after - setting relationships, cardinality and the like - but things like display names will have to be handled another way.